# Retrieving Representative Records for Unique Values of Single Column

Tags: postgresql

For Postgresql 8.x, I have an `answers` table containing `(id, user_id, question_id, choice)` where `choice` is a string value. I need a query that will return a set of records *(all columns returned)* for all unique `choice` values. What I'm looking for is a single representative record for each unique choice. I also want to have an aggregate `votes` column that is a `count()` of the number of records matching each unique choice accompanying each record. I want to force `choice` to lowercase for this comparison to be made *(**HeLLo** and **Hello** should be considered equal)*. I can't `GROUP BY lower(choice)` because I want all columns in the result-set. Grouping by all columns causes all records to return, including all duplicates.

#### 1. Closest I've gotten

```
select lower(choice), count(choice) as votes from answers where question_id = 21 group by lower(choice) order by votes desc;
```

The issue with this is it will not return all columns.

```
                     lower                     | votes 
-----------------------------------------------+-------
 dancing in the moonlight                      |     8
 pumped up kicks                               |     7
 party rock anthem                             |     6
 sexy and i know it                            |     5
 moves like jagger                             |     4
```

#### 2. Trying with all columns

```
select *, count(choice) as votes from answers where question_id = 21 group by lower(choice) order by votes desc;
```

Because I am not specifying every column from the `SELECT` in my `GROUP BY`, this throws an error telling me to do so.

#### 3. Specifying all columns in the `GROUP BY`

```
select *, count(choice) as votes from answers where question_id = 21 group by lower(choice), id, user_id, question_id, choice order by votes desc;
```

This simply dumps the table with `votes` column as `1` for all records.

How can I get the `vote` count and unique representative records from **1.**, but with *all* columns from the table returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
SELECT answers.*, cc.votes as votes FROM answers join (
    select max(id) as id, count(id) as votes 
    from answers
    group by trim(lower(choice))
) cc 
on answers.id = cc.id ORDER BY votes desc, lower(response) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Join grouped results back with primary table, then show only one row for each (question,answer) combination.

similar to this:

```
WITH top5 AS (
  select question_id, lower(choice) as choice, count(*) as votes 
  from answers 
  where question_id = 21 
  group by question_id , lower(choice) 
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 5
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON(question_id,choice) *
FROM top5 
JOIN answers USING(question_id,lower(choice))
ORDER BY question_id, lower(choice), answers.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and effort. See my answer for what I ended up using in my application.